# How to show multi select drop down border and click any where to show

Tags: css, angular

1.How to show multi select drop down border

2.To select the dropdown list to dropdown, must click the down arrow, anywhere else will not work

```
 <p-multiSelect  [options]="tList[i].t" formControlName="selectedT" defaultLabel="" ></p-multiSelect>
```

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WPtB.png)

Answer (score 0):

try to explain better what you exactly need.
Like adding some screenshots.

Comment: added screen shot. multi select drop down border need to show.

Comment: nice, in that case let me suggest you using angular material.
in this page you can find some links on how to use that:
https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview